# Using GetTable() gives the error 'type T must be a reference type'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to add a generic Insert method using GetTable() with my repository pattern with EntityFramework( hopefully I have got the pattern right)

But I am getting the error as show in the comment below.

I actually want to insert records in the database regardless of the type of the table
 Any help greatly appreciated :)

This is my BaseRepository generic class

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T>
{
    private static DBEntities dbEntities;

     public BaseRepository()
    {
        dbEntities = new DBEntities();
    }
    public IQueryable GetTable<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
    return dbEntities.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

public void Insert<T>(T obj)
{
    //the line below gives an error 'The Type T must be a reference type
    // in order to use it as parameter T. I HAVE tried adding ref here
    // and in GetTable method, but same error
    var table = GetTable(obj);        
    int saveChanges = dbEntities.SaveChanges();

}
```

}

Comment: 1) If the class has a generic type parameter, you shouldn't repeat that parameter on methods. 2) The `T : class` constraint needs to be on `BaseRepository<T>`, not on the methods.

Comment: "I HAVE tried adding ref here" suggests a confusion in your mind between reference *types* and reference *parameters*, which could be cleared up by a thorough reading of [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change your code:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private static DBEntities dbEntities;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        dbEntities = new DBEntities();
    }
    public IQueryable GetTable(T entity) 
    {
        return dbEntities.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public void Insert(T obj)
    {
       //the line below gives an error 'The Type T must be a reference type
       // in order to use it as parameter T. I HAVE tried adding ref here
       // and in GetTable method, but same error
       var table = GetTable(obj);        
       int saveChanges = dbEntities.SaveChanges();    
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. I shouldnt have put < T > next to the method names :D thx